# libstreaming record video functionality

Tags: video-streaming, libstreaming

There's a way to use the libstreaming (https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/) to record the video to a local file ?
Can someone explain the way to do it o some cose to build this functionality ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Record the video via the client for example: mplayer o ffplay

Regards.